# Finite element approximation of the cofactor matrix of the Jacobian

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation, approximation-theory, linear-approximation

Let $\Omega = (0,1)^d$ and assume there is a tensor product mesh $\mathcal T_h$ of quadrilaterals, of maximum diameter $h$, covering $\overline \Omega$, i.e., $\overline{\Omega}= \bigcup_{K\in\mathcal T_h}K$.

Let $\mathbf F:\Omega \to \mathbb R^d$ be such that

- $\mathbf F|_K$ belongs to $C^\infty$;
- $\mathbf F$ is, at least, of class $C^2(\overline{\Omega})$.

Let $\overline{\mathbf F}_h$ be a multilinear piecewise nodal interplant of $\mathbf F$ on $\mathcal T_h$.

The following interpolation estimate holds:
\begin{equation}
\| |\det D \mathbf F| D \mathbf F^{-T}- |\det D\overline {\mathbf F}_h| D \overline {\mathbf{F}}_h^{-T}\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \le C h \| D\mathbf F\|^{d-1}_{L^\infty(\Omega)} \frac{\| D^2 \mathbf F\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}}{ \|D\mathbf F\|_{L^\infty(\Omega)}}.
\end{equation}

I do not have any intuition about the above estimate. Moreover, I cannot find anything similar in the literature. Any help?

Just a little remark: the term $|\det D \mathbf F| D \mathbf F^{-T}= \operatorname{Cof} (D\mathbf F)$ is the [cofactor matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Inverse_of_a_matrix) of $D\mathbf F$.